# Waiting logic for inactivity

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a TimeBomb object. I have to make the bomb to explode based on a timing logic. The bomb will wait for max 10 seconds and in that time interval, if no one in that interval resets the bomb to the latest time it will explode. I have come up with an implementation. I am starting the waiting logic by setting the timer to the current time say at 16:24:40. Now the bomb is all set to explode at 16:24:50. After sleeping for 2 seconds I am resetting the bomb to the current time to 16:24:42. Now the bomb should explode only at 16:24:52 since the max waiting period is 10 seconds.But the logic I implemented always explodes at 16:24:50. Where I am doing wrong ?

```
public class TestTimeBomb {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TimeBomb bomb = new TimeBomb();
        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("First setting event at time " + getHumanReadableTime(time1));
        bomb.resetBomb(time1);
        Job job = new Job(bomb);
        new Thread(job).start();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Second setting event at time " + getHumanReadableTime(time2));
        bomb.resetBomb(time2);
    }

    public static Date getHumanReadableTime(long time) {
        Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(time);
        Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
        return date;
    }
}

class Job implements Runnable {

    TimeBomb bomb;

    Job(TimeBomb bomb) {
        this.bomb = bomb;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        WaiterLogic waiterLogic = new WaiterLogic(bomb);
        new Thread(waiterLogic).start();
    }
}

class WaiterLogic implements Runnable {
    private TimeBomb test;

    WaiterLogic(TimeBomb test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Entering while loop this job should end at " + TestTimeBomb.getHumanReadableTime(currentTimeMillis + 10000));
        while (true) {
            long bombTime = test.getBombTime();
            long curentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diffTIme = curentTime - bombTime;
            if (diffTIme > 10000) 
                break;

        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("This job should have ended at" + TestTimeBomb.getHumanReadableTime(test.getBombTime() + 10000));
        System.out.println("But ended at time " + TestTimeBomb.getHumanReadableTime(end));
        System.out.println("Diff is " + (end - (test.getBombTime() + 10000)));
    }

}

class TimeBomb {

    private long bombTime;

    public long getBombTime() {
        return bombTime;
    }

    public void resetBomb(long bombTime) {
        this.bombTime = bombTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is working as expected

Comment: First setting event at time Fri Apr 08 17:29:11 IST 2016
Entering while loop this job should end at Fri Apr 08 17:29:21 IST 2016
Second setting event at time Fri Apr 08 17:29:13 IST 2016
This job should have ended atFri Apr 08 17:29:23 IST 2016
But ended at time Fri Apr 08 17:29:21 IST 2016
Diff is -2028

Comment: This is what i am getting with same program `First setting event at time Fri Apr 08 17:32:01 IST 2016
Entering while loop this job should end at Fri Apr 08 17:32:12 IST 2016
Second setting event at time Fri Apr 08 17:32:04 IST 2016
This job should have ended atFri Apr 08 17:32:14 IST 2016
But ended at time Fri Apr 08 17:32:14 IST 2016
Diff is 1`

Comment: No @Sanjeev. The while loop ends 2 seconds earlier than expected.

Comment: I ran your code multiple times and it works as expected always ends with a diff=1 ms

Comment: Same for me @Sanjeev. Also tried different time configurations but I was not able to reproduce the error. Maybe different SOs have their ownway to treat threads. I think maybe flkes answer is the way to go.

Comment: Mine a system with four core processors. Using volatile keyword fixed the issue effectively.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a concurrency issue, where the `bombTime` variable is not thread safe.

On one thread (`main`) you're setting the value in `bombTime` and in a different thread  (`WaiterLogic`) you're reading the value. There is a race condition where if these two threads try to get this data at the same time, the data cached in each thread may become inconsistent.

There are a couple of options to make this operation thread-safe

---

**Use synchronization**

The `synchronized` keyword is used to let a thread lock an object while it performs a task. `synchronized` can be used be used on the `TimeBomb` class methods like so:

```
class TimeBomb {

    private long bombTime;

    public synchronized long getBombTime() {
        return bombTime;
    }

    public synchronized void resetBomb(long bombTime) {
        this.bombTime = bombTime;
    }
}
```

by adding `synchronized` to each method, the main thread will have to wait to access the timebomb object if the `WaiterLogic` thread is calling `getBombTime`. Similarly, the `WaiterLogic` thread will wait to access the timebomb object if the main thread is calling `resetBomb`. This ensures that each thread will cache the correct copy of the `bombTime` data.

---

**Use volatile keyword**

The `volatile` keyword makes it such that a thread never caches a value. it will always go straight to memory, essentially acting as if it were in synchronized block.

```
private volatile long bombTime;
```

---

**Use an atomic object**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) describes an atomic object:

> In concurrent programming, an operation (or set of operations) is atomic, linearizable, indivisible or uninterruptible if it appears to the rest of the system to occur instantaneously.

In java you can use `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong` for this purpose. This object requires no `volatile` or `synchronized` keywords. It is all handled by the class itself.

```
class TimeBomb {

    private AtomicLong atomicBombTime;

    public long getBombTime() {
        return atomicBombTime.get();
    }

    public void resetBomb(long bombTime) {
        atomicBombTime.set(bombTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wait(10000) and notify (in resetBomb method) instead looping, it's less time consuming.